# Calling insert on string but nothing happening

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert the elements of one string, **message**, into another, **alphabet**, at intervals with equal spacing.

```
string message = "my name jeff";
string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
size_t spacing{26/message.size()}, i{0};
for(size_t j = 0; j < message.size(); ++j)
{
   alphabet.insert(i, message[j], 1);
   i+=spacing;
}
cout << alphabet;
```

The output, however, is the same as the original alphabet string and I'm not sure why. Would greatly appreciate some help with this.

Comment: what's up with the weird "spacing" ?

Comment: Take a closer look at [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert).

Comment: @AndersK I'm writing an encryption project and we have to insert the decryption key in the encrypted message in a way that it can be easily extracted, so I made it so that they are inserted at equal intervals uniformly throughout the message.

Comment: @Elec1 I tried but the same thing is happening.

Comment: @AlejandroEspino, This approach is going to frontload the decryption key because there's one extra character being counted in the index per insertion already done.

Answer (score 1):

You have the 2nd and 3rd parameters of `insert()` backwards.  The 2nd parameter expects the `count` of the `ch`aracter specified in the 3rd parameter.  So, you are inserting `message[j]` number of `'\x01'` characters, which is why you don't see anything because `0x01` is a non-printable control character.

You need to change this:

```
alphabet.insert(i, message[j], 1);
```

To this instead:

```
alphabet.insert(i, 1, message[j]);
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/kUlpnv)

Note, your current logic won't distribute the letters of `message` *evenly* throughout `alphabet`, because `26/12=2` in integer math, so you will fill up only 1/2 of `alphabet`:

```
mayb cndaemfeg hjiejfkflmnopqrstuvwxyz
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

In this case, you would need to calculate the `spacing` as `(26/12)+1=3` instead:

```
size_t spacing{(alphabet.size() / message.size()) + ((alphabet.size()  %message.size()) ? 1 : 0)};
```

Which will get you a little bit of a more even distribution:

```
mabycd efnghaijmklemn opjqrestfuvfwxyz
^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/V3zNFp)

Note that it is still favoring the front of the `alphabet` string, though.  The first index you insert `message` at should be at `(3/2)+1=2` rather than at `0`:

```
size_t i{(spacing / 2) + ((spacing % 2) ? 1 : 0)};
```

```
abmcdyef ghnijaklmmneop qrjsteuvfwxfyz
  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/LumEyZ)

Comment: That did it, just my lack of attention to detail. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you so much Remy, I would've spent a good chunk of time trying to figure out what was wrong if it weren't for your help here.